# Marketing Cloud - how to monitor API calls for errors

Tags: marketing-cloud

I just wanted to know if there is any kind of log that we can access via Automation or dataview to retrieve more information when we get errors in our API calls.

thanks

Comment: You don't have any data views as such as per the official documentation, but you can write the errors in a DE and maintain the log locally in your instance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only place to get more information on your API calls is from support and honestly it is not much more information than what you receive in your responses and it can take a bit to get it to the right person to review and respond.

As of current state, there is no way to get more information on API call responses or errors on your own. Your best bet is to log the responses you get inside of a database and connect that response with the descriptions in **[SFMC SOAP API ERROR CODES](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error_codes.htm)** and **[REST API ERROR CODES](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm)**.

It really kind of sucks, but that is all there is.

Do remember that if the call is successful, but the action errors, it will still return a 200 status code, despite not working. So account for that in your logging.